# How to add a value in the last part of the value in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Just want to ask i have a value already in my sql database. what i want is to add -DT in every value in the TOBUSID column. using vb.net

The value in my database is like this

CONN                                  INSTTYPE                       TOBUSID
1                                   PAD MOUNTED               M3F4J6-04001-1
1                                   POLE MOUNTED              M3F4J6-04002-1
1                                   PAD MOUNTED               M3F4J6-04003-1

what i want is to look like this

CONN                         INSTTYPE                                TOBUSID
1                          PAD MOUNTED                     M3F4J6-04001-1-DT
1                          POLE MOUNTED                    M3F4J6-04002-1-DT
1                          PAD MOUNTED                     M3F4J6-04003-1-DT

Anyone please help

Comment: Have you looked at the concat() method is SQL?

Comment: What about `UPDATE your_table SET TOBUSID = CONCAT(TOBUSID, '-DT')`?

Comment: not yet sir actually i serch for the concat code but i have no luck

Answer (score 0):

You could use CONCAT function
(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
UPDATE your_table SET TOBUSID = CONCAT(TOBUSID, '-DT')
```